# Replace 2 characters within a reversed string at once

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
myString = "test (with (w)ords) swap"
```

reverse the string and swap ( with ) and ) with (

output: `"paws (sdro(w) htiw) tset"`

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: all there... forgot it when typing it in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could reverse the string via slicing and (for Python 3) use `str.translate` with the appropriate `str.maketrans` mapping:

```
>>> s = "test (with (w)ords) swap"
>>> s[::-1].translate(str.maketrans('()', ')('))
'paws (sdro(w) htiw) tset'
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for python2:

```
from string import maketrans
reversed = myString[::-1].translate(maketrans(")(", "()"))
```

Output:

```
paws (sdro(w) htiw) tset
```